# How to return to the first test class after another class in testNG xml scenario

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I tryed to use several classes in testNG in single test scenario. It must execute few methods from first class, then from second, and back to the first class again. But after execution first class previews methods test finished as successful, and another methods not execute (last method - logonSuccess)

```
<test name="WithdrawCCC">
<parameter name="param_one" value="value"/>
<parameter name="param_two" value="value"/>


<classes>

    <class name="Class_one">
        <methods>
            <include name="openURL"/>
            <include name="vaidateElementsOnPage"/>
            <include name="authTry"/>
            <include name="logonSuccess"/>
        </methods>
    </class>

    <class name="Class_two">
        <methods>
            <include name="vaidateElementsOnPage"/>
            <include name="checkForTransaction"/>
        </methods>
    </class>

    <class name="Class_one">
        <methods>
            <include name="refreshCurrentPage"/>
            <include name="checkTransactionStatus"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
</classes>
```

How I can solve this trouble?

Comment: what you need to do is create one @Test method and from there call other methods and assert their outcome.

Answer (score 0):

TestNg runs test class methods in the order in which they are defined in the xml file unless you configure it otherwise using thread priorities or "dependson" attribute. Unless you see the test class codes you cant really pinpoint the error
Here is one way to do this
Create Groups and use dependsOnGroup.

If you want logonSuccess to run after every method , add all other methods in the same group and use dependsOngroup on logonSuccess.

Let me show with an example. I want the bouncer test to execute after all methods from both classes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="IPL" verbose="0"  >
    <test name="cricketTest">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.basic.thread.BallTest"></class>
        <class name="com.basic.thread.BatTest"></class>
    </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The first test class

```
public class BallTest {
  @Test(groups="first")
  public void yorker() {
      System.out.println("yorker");
  }
  @Test(dependsOnGroups={"first"})
  public void bouncer() {

      System.out.println("bouncer ");
  }
}
```

The second test class

```
public class BatTest {
  @Test(groups="first")
  public void Pull() {
      System.out.println("Pull ");
  }
  @Test(groups="first")
  public void StraightDrive() {
      System.out.println("Straight ");
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:
yorker
Pull 
Straight
bouncer

Comment: Your answer does not content required explanation .

Comment: why he was getting error , if you can explain him the concept and that will be also helpful to the people who are coming to see and learn for years. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: TestNg runs test class methods  in the order in which they are defined in the xml file unless you configure it otherwise using thread priorities or "dependson" attribute. Unless you see the test class codes you cant really pinpoint the error .

Comment: add it to your answer.